# Filtering a Pivot Table Automatically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a DB for school activities in the afternoon. I'm trying to create a search option through a form that controls a pivot table in which the user can filter on the class type and/or the age group and or the school year.

I wrote this code in VBA and it's not working. When i tried to write a code to filter on only one of the above (such as class type) it worked but when I expanded it to 3 filter options it isn't working. It fails when no value is inserted in one of the options.

```
search_class.Hide
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("class type").ClearAllFilters

If IsNull(Range("type_search").Value) Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("class type").CurrentPage = "(All)"
Else: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("class type").CurrentPage = Range("type_search").Value
End If

type_box = "pick a class type"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("group age").ClearAllFilters

If IsNull(Range("target_search").Value) Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("group age").CurrentPage = "(All)"
Else: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("group age").CurrentPage = Range("target_search").Value
End If

target_box = "pick a group age"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("school year").ClearAllFilters

If IsNull(Range("year_search").Value) Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("school year").CurrentPage = "(All)"
Else:
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotFields("school year").CurrentPage = Range("year_search").Value
End If

year_search_box = "pick a school year"   

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSearchClass").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Does anyone know ehat the problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work if you change your tests to either:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("type_search").Value)
```

or

```
If Range("type_search").Value = ""
```

`IsNull` is used to test whether a variant variable contains a null value, which won't be true with either a blank or filled cell.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You should accept it, and any other helpful ones you've gotten, by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel on this computer and pivot tables are my weakness but I'll try to help since you seem alone on this. First make sure your script is indeed running the "True" case of your if statement and then I would edit the value of CurrentPage to see if your issue is there (i.e., change the "(all)" value to something else). Where does the error lie and what is the error description?

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer.                               If Range("type_search").Value = ""
solved it!